# I'm getting a Gradle error on Unity with my Macbook M1 computer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I have a MacBook Pro M1 computer and I installed the Unity program with version 2021.3.23f1 Silicon LTS through Unity Hub, which was the recommended version for me. Then, I also installed OpenJDK and Android SDK & NDK Tools from Unity Hub. I tried this with the 2020 and 2022 versions as well, but I keep getting the same errors while building. I also tried different SDK, JDK, NDK and Gradle versions, including 7.0 and 8.0, as well as the one installed by Unity Hub, but it didn't work. Please help me, I would appreciate any assistance.

[image: My errors]

I have reinstalled everything from scratch and tried again multiple times, but I'm still getting the same result. I haven't seen anyone else experiencing this problem. It seems like the issue might be with the gradle version, but I have also tried different gradle versions with no success.

My Errors;

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0-rc-2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
36 actionable tasks: 36 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, /Users/mucahitsoylemez/Developing/AR/MobileAR/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/Mono2x/Gradle/unityLibrary/build/generated/ap_generated_sources/release/out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@6e43377d) before task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU??LD FAILED in 23s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.23f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Library/gradle-7.0-rc-2/lib/gradle-launcher-7.0.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446282
XPC_SERVICE_NAME = application.com.unity3d.unityhub.15805544.15806423
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
XPC_FLAGS = 0x0
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
MallocNanoZone = 0
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined
SHELL = /bin/zsh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.JqPCTQGSdQ/Listeners
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
__CFBundleIdentifier = com.unity3d.unityhub
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
HOME = /Users/mucahitsoylemez
USER = mucahitsoylemez
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446283
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0x23:0x18
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
TMPDIR = /var/folders/jf/1w5dmj6d7mvcstsr08n3qfyw0000gn/T/
LOGNAME = mucahitsoylemez
JAVA_HOME = /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.23f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
COMMAND_MODE = unix2003


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, /Users/mucahitsoylemez/Developing/AR/MobileAR/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/Mono2x/Gradle/unityLibrary/build/generated/ap_generated_sources/release/out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@6e43377d) before task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU??LD FAILED in 23s
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0-rc-2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
36 actionable tasks: 36 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:370)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 60 seconds (60170 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

i got this error in gradle version 6.1.1

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Note: /Users/mucahitsoylemez/Developing/AR/MobileAR/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/Mono2x/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/Users/mucahitsoylemez/.android/debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU??LD FAILED in 25s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Thanks to the @shingo. The problem was resolved when a new keystore was created.

Comment: Please [don't post image of error](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), copy all the errors from the editor log.

Comment: Ok, i edited my comment. I copied all errors. thx for notice

Comment: 7.0-rc-2 seems to be a wrong gradle version, I'm not sure if Unity on mac includes a gradle, it's path should be `<Unity>/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle`. If not you need to install a compatible version (6.1.1 in this case) https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.2/Documentation/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html

Comment: i tried default gradle version (default version path as you said. and its version is 6.1.1). But didn't work.

Comment: Same error? The last error is this line `Failed to query the value of task...`

Comment: No, this time i have this error;                                                                      
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/Users/mucahitsoylemez/.android/debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

Comment: Try to create your own keystore in the android player settings.

Comment: @shingo Thank you so much my problem has been resolved. I hope you have a great day. God bless you and be your helper.